# Trying to use Toast message, but get error

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a Toast message inside a listener method, but I get an error saying something like: Toast is not applicable for the argument.. I don't understand this and can't solve this problem without some help? Thanks!

```
        // Button 1
    button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //text_1.setText("New text for first row!"); // Change text
            Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked on number 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(controlImage_1)
            {
                image_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_1b); // Change image
                controlImage_1 = false;
            }
            else
            {
                image_1.setImageResource(R.drawable.android_1a); // Change image
                controlImage_1 = true;
            }
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Your download has resumed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
Toast.makeText(**YourClassName.this**, "You have clicked on number 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Without * =)

Answer (score 1):

```
Toast.makeText(this, "You have clicked on number 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Your `this` in this statement refers to the `View.OnClickListener` you created. Read more on anonymous inner classes.

Use `MyActivity.this` instead

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the `Context` of the current `Activity` as the first argument. You can't just say `this` in this case because it is not referring to the application context. You can either create a variable in your on create and use that context or just do this...

```
Toast.makeText([CLASS_NAME].this, "You have clicked on number 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Replace `[CLASS_NAME]` with the class that is extending `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Try getApplicationContext() as first argument for Toast.makeText or MyActivity.this

here in your code , this refers to the View

Also, if button_1 needs to have onclick listener by default and you are using API > 7,its nice to define onclick="myclickfunction" in the layout itself. Cleans up your code and easy to modify...

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using it in the onClick Listener method, you cannot use only *this* as the first parameter.

```
Toast.makeText(ClassName.this, "You have clicked on number 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Use your classname.this as the first parameter.